# GlobalKtable initialization duration

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, debezium, rocksdb

I am looking for advices.
I have to work with GlobalKtables for consuming heavies topics and make join with my processor.
Joins concerns a **80Go - 8 partitions** topic and **50Go single partition** topic.

When my java processor starts it creates 2 GlobalKTables bases ont this 2 topics.
While consuming this I do my business and everything is ok.

I tested it with a very very small amount of data on each topics and it works fine.
Here is a snipet of GKT init:

```
myStreamBuilder.globalTable(myTopicName, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), myDbziumSerdes))
```

BUT, when deployed on my env with heavies topics like previously described, i's been 8hours since my app seems to 'init' GlobalKTables. And no new event seems to be processed.

**Questions:**

- Is my usage of GlobalKTables ok?
- What's the impact on memory footprints for my processor to mount
  these GlobalKTables?
- Is there any other better approach?

I thought about using a database instead of GlobalKTables to prevent this init time, but it needs te redevelop a major part of the processor.

*Env:
Java 14
Kafka 2.5.1*

Answer (score 0):

Using a `GlobalKTable` means that the Kafka topic will be fully replicated to each `KafkaStreams` that belongs to your `application.id`, either in memory or on disk (i.e. RocksDB) depending on how you materialise your `StateStore`.

A `GlobalKTable` is used to perfom a join with a `KStream` using a join-key that can be different from the key of the input streamw without having to repartition the input topics.

Typically, `GlobalKTable` are used to materialize a topic containing reference data or data that slowly changing over time.

One drawback of `GlobalKTable` is that KafkaStreams only use a single global thread to manage all global tables. This is why the initialization of multiple `GlobalKTable` can take a while, a few seconds to hours.

To optimize initialization you can override/increased those settings:

```
// for global consumer (default values).
streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.globalConsumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG), 1000);
streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.globalConsumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG), 52428800);
streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.globalConsumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG), 1048576);
streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.globalConsumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.RECEIVE_BUFFER_CONFIG), 65536);
```

Moreover, the input topics for the `GlobalKTable` should be compacted (i.e. `cleanup.policy=compact`). Also, you may try to reduce the segment size of your topic (for example to 100MB) to increase the frequency of segment rotation and thus to have a more aggressive compaction.